# Logging back in after auth token expires

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I get:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: auth() was canceled: Auth token is expired
```

It seems logging back in does not work unless i refresh the app once token has expired.

```
var loginService = $firebaseSimpleLogin(new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI));

     var _login = function() {
        loginService.$login('google').then(function(user) {
            _setCurrentUser(user);
            $state.go('app.decisions');
        }, function(error) {
            console.error('Unable to login', error);
        });
    };
```

_login() does not open the Google login popup

Comment: Can you try to update to the latest version of Simple Login (1.6.1)? So, load it from https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.1/firebase-simple-login.js and see if that fixes your problem.